# Jquery Hover Effect, Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, hover

I am using Bootstrap columns. When someone hovers over the img, I want the `<p>` to slideToggle. I currently have this set, but, I want it to display only for the selected item and not for the remaining `<p>`'s in the same div element.

For example, when somebody hovers over the image of column #1, I want the `<p>` for column #1 to display only, and not all the other `<p>` of the other columns. Here is my jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  $("#columns img").hover(function() {
    $(this).children("#columns p").each(function() {
      $(this).slideToggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="columns">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="..." onload="this.width/=2;">
      <h3>First Column</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at.
    </div>
    <!-- end column -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="..." onload="this.width/=2;">
      <h3>Second Column</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end column -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="..." onload="this.width/=2;">
      <h3>Third Column</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end column -->
  </div>
  <!-- end row -->
</div>
<!-- end columns id -->
```

Comment: It makes no sense to try and look for children of an image element … images don’t have children.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be malformed, so i'm just assuming you can't target your `p` element. Using this calls `slideToggle()` on a hovered image's corresponding `p` element.

```
$(function(){
    $("#columns img").hover(function() {
      $(this).parent().find("p").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Again...I've already gone so. If I may ask... I'm creating a (bootstrap) one-page website. When each section  loads, I want effects to take place. Is this a CSS trick or is it still JQuery? I've been messing around with JQuery, but I haven't been lucky. What is the event handler that you use when a section loads. Please could you show me an example.

Comment: You can [acceppt](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) an answer to indicate it has been solved. If you have a new question, please create a new Q/A post, if you want to, you can link it to me and i will look into it when i have time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you wrap your description part for each `img` i.e. `h3` and `p` tags corresponding to each `img`, in a `div` and hide it at first instance, and on hover you show it. Take a below example. I've wrapped your descriptions for each image into a `div` with `class-desc`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#columns img").on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).siblings(".desc").show('slow',function(){
          $('.desc').not($(this)).hide('fast'); //hide all desc except current
    }) //show only the sibling desc of current image
  });
});
```

```css
.desc {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="columns">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="..." onload="this.width/=2;">
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>First Column</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at.
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end column -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="..." onload="this.width/=2;">
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Second Column</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end column -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="..." onload="this.width/=2;">
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Third Column</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end column -->
  </div>
  <!-- end row -->
</div>
<!-- end columns id -->
```

Now if you want to only show `p` tag and `h3` will always be displayed, then you can avoid wrapping into `desc div` and do as below:

```
$("#columns img").on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).siblings('p').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want. In order to slideToggle you initially need to hide the paragraphs.
Now whichever image you hover, `closest('div')` will find the closest parent div and then we find the 'p' inside of it to toggle its display.

```js
$(function(){
    $('p').hide();
    $("#columns img").hover(function() {
      $(this).closest("div").find("p").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="columns">
<div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                       <img src="..." onload="this.width/=2;">
                       <h3>First Column</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at.
                   </div><!-- end column -->
                   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                       <img src="..." onload="this.width/=2;">
                       <h3>Second Column</h3>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at.</p>
                   </div><!-- end column -->
                   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                       <img src="..." onload="this.width/=2;">
                       <h3>Third Column</h3>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit convallis nisl, eget rutrum lectus commodo at.</p>
                 </div><!-- end column -->  
 </div><!-- end row --> 
 </div><!-- end columns id -->
```